# differential equations BVP

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

```py
#including the differential equations and parameters 

def model(x,dydx,p): 
    s=p[0]  #first parameter 
    a=p[1]   #second parameter 

    dydx[0] = -2*(s+a)*y[0]+2*s*y[1]+s/2*y[2] 
    dydx[1] = +2*(s+a)*y[1]-2*s*y[0]-s/2*y[2] 
    dydx[2] = -(s+a)*y[2] 

    return np.vstack(dydx[0],dydx[1],dydx[2]) 

# boundary conditions

def bc(ya, yb,yc, p): 
    s=p[0]  
    a=p[1] 
    I0=1 

    return np.array(([ya[0], yb[0],yc[0],a,s])) 
#x values 
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])   
y = np.zeros((3, x.size)) 
#p=  np.zeros((3, d.size)) 
#y initial values 
y[0]=3 
y[1]=3 
y[2]=2 

I0 = 1 

sol = solve_bvp(model, bc,x,y, p=[1,1])
```

I do not know how can I write the boundary conditions to solve the three differential equations

I want to solve the equations and have the `y` values and parameters values

Comment: What are the boundary conditions? `solve_bvp` does not treat conditions on other than the two interval end points.

Comment: Boundary value problem that my problem.I have those three differential equations I wanna solve them together to get y0 y1 y2 and parameters s and p

Comment: You should have somewhere 5 conditions, or equations, in the values `y_0(1),y_1(1),y_2(1)` and `y_0(9), y_1(9), y_2(9)`.  In the most simple case this fixes values for 5 of these 6 numbers. Then you can apply `solve_bvp` (after also fixing the `model` function declaration).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707148/the-code-is-written-in-matlab-to-solve-bvp-differential-equation-could-anyone-he?noredirect=1#comment107410708_60707148 here a matlab code that I am trying to convert it into python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the other question you have fixed parameters and 3 boundary conditions. This needs to be encoded as

```py
# boundary conditions
def bc(y0, yd, I0): 
    return np.array([y0[0], y0[2]-I0, yd[1]])
```

Then the initial `x` array needs to be bounded by the boundary points

```py
x = np.linspace(0,d,9)   
y = np.zeros((3, x.size)) 
#y initial values 
y[0]=3 
y[1]=3 
y[2]=2
```

and the solver needs to be called without variable parameters, fixing them all to their constant values via wrappers/partial evaluation

```py
sol = solve_bvp(lambda t,y:model(t,y,[s,a]), lambda y0,yd: bc(y0,yd,I0), x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but in case of the parameters are variable [s,a]  , how the boundary conditions and the solver will be? thankns in advance

Comment: As previously said, you have #(boundary conditions) = #(state variables) + #(unknown parameters), so you would need to specify 5 boundary conditions.

Comment: ValueError: `bc` return is expected to have shape (3,), but actually has (5,).I am facing this error when I want to estimate the parameters a and s as dependent parameters not constant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60851123/valueerror-bc-return-is-expected-to-have-shape-3-but-actually-has-5 I uploaded the code here.Thanks for the help